# How to project a field based on a condition in Spring data mongodb?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I am trying to fetch matching documents based on a search criteria. Everything works fine except there is a List field called priceHistory, it has two properties 1) price and 2)date for the price. I need to project the priceHisotry field only and only if today's price is available, otherwise it has to be shown as null. The priceHistory field is not a part of search criteria but only the result(Projections).

- Tried with simple Criteria but it ended up filtering based on the the
  priceHistory date field.
- Tried using $Cond but could not convert it
  into Java equivalent.
- The last resort would be to iterate over the
  resulset and achieve desired output

  ```
  "priceHistory": [
                  {
                      "price": "20019.75",
                      "dateForPrice": "Tue Sep 09 02:00:00 IST 2019"
                  },
  {
                      "price": "20234.75",
                      "dateForPrice": "Tue Sep 08 02:00:00 IST 2019"
                  }
  {
                      "price": "20234.75",
                      "dateForPrice": "Tue Sep 08 02:00:00 IST 2019"
                  }
              ]
  ```

  ConditionalOperators.when(Criteria.where("priceHistory.price").gte(todaysDate))
                                  .then(dynamicQuery.fields().include(value)).otherwise("");

Is there a way that I can add this condition to the Query object, so that DB could work for it instead iterating over each document and manipulating the response.?

Answer (score 0):

You can filter field "priceHistory" in your MongoDB query as follow:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
    $project: {
        priceHistory: {
            $filter: {
                input: "$priceHistory",
                as: "ph",
                cond: {
                    $and: [
                        { $gte: ["$$ph.dateForPrice", start] },   // start time of the day 00:00:00 
                        { $lte: ["$$ph.dateForPrice", end ]  }    // end time of the day 23:59:59
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }        
}
```

])

Dynamically pass the start and end date and time from the current date. This will filter out price history.